# Number format of axes in a plot

Tags: plotting, options, labeling

How can I have a conditional format of the values appearing in the axis of a plot ?

I have in mind the number format options available in Excel for plots as described here http://peltiertech.com/Excel/NumberFormats.html.

I'm mostly interested in how to format numbers as shown in the paragraph "Thousands, Millions, etc." in order to display 100 000 as 100k and 100 000 000 as 100M for example.

Also is it possible to set this format by default in plots ?

Comment: This can be done, with a bit of effort/code, by writing a function `f` to generate the appropriate ticks specification, and then use `Ticks -> {Automatic, f}`.  But you'll have to determine tick placement, size, etc... on your own (`FindDivisions` is useful here.)

Comment: See [my answer here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/831/5). That gives a general way to format the ticks as you want — you just need to replace the `xTicks` function with your own logic to convert 10^8 as 100 M, etc.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

One can also define a `KMB` number format using `NumberForm` and its options as follows:

```
 g[a_] := Switch[a, "3", "K", "6", "M", "9", "B", "12", "T", _, ""]; 
 kmbtForm[num_?NumericQ, digits_?IntegerQ] := 
 StringReplace[#, "." ~~ x : ("K" | "M" | "B" | "T") -> x] &@
 ToString@
 NumberForm[N@#1, #2, 
  ExponentFunction -> (If[0 >= #, 0, 3 Quotient[#, 3]] &), 
  NumberFormat -> (StringJoin[#1, g[#3]] &)] & @@ {num, digits}
```

Usage examples:

```
  {kmbtForm[#, 3], kmbtForm[#, 4]} & 
   /@ {-1234, 12.34, 12345.67, 123456.7, 1234567., 123456789.123, 1234567891.} // Grid
```

gives

[image]

For plot ticks, using a variation of Faysal's tick function with this formatting function

```
 tickfunc[xmin_, xmax_] := 
 Function[tickNumber, {tickNumber, kmbtForm[tickNumber, 3]}] /@ 
 FindDivisions[{xmin, xmax}, 10];
```

in

```
 Plot[1000 x^3, {x, -10, 10}, Ticks -> {Automatic, tickfunc}]
```

gives

[image]

Comment: This looks quite flexible. +1

Comment: Indeed, +1 and accept.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard and Faysal, Thank you for the vote and accept.

Answer (score 9):

Here's what I've come up with based on the comment of Brett and the example of Chris that suits what I wanted.

```
tickNumberFormat[xmin_,xmax_]:=
Function[tickNumber,
    {
        tickNumber
        ,
        Which[
            Abs@tickNumber>=10^9,
                StringReplace[ToString[tickNumber/10.^9]~~"bn",".bn"->"bn"],

            Abs@tickNumber>=10^6,
                StringReplace[ToString[tickNumber/10.^6]~~"m",".m"->"m"],

            Abs@tickNumber>=10^3,
                StringReplace[ToString[tickNumber/10.^3]~~"k",".k"->"k"],

            True,
                tickNumber
        ]
    }
]/@FindDivisions[{xmin,xmax},10];

SetOptions[Plot, Ticks -> {Automatic, tickNumberFormat}];

Plot[1000 x^3,{x,-10,10}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

As Brett mentions, for example:

```
yticks = {#*10^6, ToString[#] <> "m"} & /@ (Range[10]*4);
ListPlot[Prime[Range[25]*10^5], Filling -> Axis, Ticks -> {Automatic, yticks}]
```

[image]