# ListLogLinearPlot logarithmic axis tickmarks

Tags: plotting, manipulate

When using [`ListLogLinearPlot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ListLogLinearPlot.html) the abscissa labels every other decade.

Is there a way to tell Mathematica to label each decade?

I need to use this inside [`Manipulate`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Manipulate.html) where the axes will scale according to the chosen variable.

[image]

Here is some example code of the kind I am using:

```
s[x_] := (10^-9) x^2; t[x_] := (10^-3) x^2; 
Manipulate[ ListLogLinearPlot[{ Table[{a s[T], T}, {T, 0, 1000}], 
 Table[{a t[T], T}, {T, 0, 1000}] }, 
 GridLines -> None, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005]}, Joined -> True, 
 PlotRange -> Automatic], {a, 10^-8, 10^8}]
```

Comment: Could you please give an example of code - best the one producing this graphics, or your manipulate.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/) could help, see CustomTicksGuide.pdf, p. 4.

Comment: @VitaliyKaurov `s[x_] := (10^-9) x^2;
t[x_] := (10^-3) x^2;
Manipulate[
 ListLogLinearPlot[{
   Table[{a s[T], T}, {T, 0, 1000}],
   Table[{a t[T], T}, {T, 0, 1000}]
   },
  GridLines -> None,
  PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005]},
  Joined -> True,
  PlotRange -> Automatic], {a, 10^-8, 10^8}]`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can create some custom ticks that work the way you want. There might be a better way than `Superscript`, but I couldn't work out how to get `ScientificForm` or `NumberForm` to just show the exponent rather than `1 x 10^4` etc.

```
myTicks = Table[{10^i, Superscript[10, i]}, {i, -20, 15}]
```

Notice I've changed the way the `a` variable enters into the `Manipulate`, as it will give you more chance to explore some of the lower-exponent values.

```
Manipulate[
 ListLogLinearPlot[{Table[{10^a s[T], T}, {T, 0, 1000}], 
   Table[{10^a t[T], T}, {T, 0, 1000}]}, GridLines -> None, 
  Ticks -> {myTicks, Automatic}, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005]}, 
  Joined -> True, PlotRange -> Automatic], {a, -8, 8}]
```

[image]

Comment: ListLogLinearPlot[] uses Superscript[] too ... so it seems the way to go.

Comment: Thanks @Verbeia, this works just fine. I am now trying to implement this into `FrameTicks` where the upper horizontal tick marks are shown but without the decade labels, but this isn't a major concern.

Answer (score 5):

One can adapt [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3539/125) answer to a smilar question to define a number format as follows:

```
 exponentForm[num_?NumericQ] := 
 ToString@NumberForm[N@#1, ExponentFunction -> (# &), NumberFormat -> (#3 &)] &@num
```

Applied to a portion of Verbeia'a tick list, this function gives

[image]

You can use it to define custom ticks with exponent labels:

```
  myExpTicks = Table[{10^i, exponentForm[10^i]}, {i, -20, 15}];
```

And, finally use it in your `Manipulate` as

```
 Manipulate[
 ListLogLinearPlot[{Table[{10^a s[T], T}, {T, 0, 1000}], 
 Table[{10^a t[T], T}, {T, 0, 1000}]}, GridLines -> None, 
 Ticks -> {myExpTicks, Automatic}, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005]}, 
 Joined -> True, PlotRange -> Automatic], {a, -8, 8}]
```

to get

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can create custom ticks and use `ListPlot` :

```
myTicks[lower_, upper_, step_] := Flatten[Module[{Local = #, LocalTicks}, 
 LocalTicks = Log[10, Range[10^(# - 1), 10^#, (10^# - 10^(# - 1))/(10 - 1)]]; 
 Join[{#, ""} & /@ Most[LocalTicks], {{Last[LocalTicks], Power[10, 
 ToString[Last[LocalTicks]]] }}]] & /@ Range[lower, upper, step], 1]

Manipulate[ListPlot[{Table[{Log[10, a s[T]], T}, {T, 0, 1000}], Table[{Log[10, 
 a t[T]], T}, {T, 0, 1000}]}, GridLines -> None, PlotStyle -> {Thickness[0.005]}, 
 Joined -> True, PlotRange -> Automatic, Ticks -> {myTicks[lower, upper, step],
  Automatic}, AxesOrigin -> {lower, 0}], {{lower, -20, "lower"}},
  {{upper, 10, "upper"}}, {{step, 1, "step"}}, Delimiter, {a, 10^-8, 10^8}]
```

[image: customTicks]