# About the number format in ticks

Tags: plotting, output-formatting, labeling, ticks

I want to `LogPlot` a function, but I have the trouble in the number format in the ticks.

For example,

```
LogPlot[Abs[BesselJ[1, x] Sin[x]^2], {x, -10, 10},
   Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {None, None}}]
```

The output is

[image: Plot output]

If I use the command

```
LogPlot[Abs[BesselJ[1, x] Sin[x]^2], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True,  
  FrameTicks -> {
    {{#, HoldForm[#]} & /@ {10^0, 10^-1, 10^-2, 10^-3, 10^-4, 10^-5}, None},
    {None, None}
   }
]
```

I can get

[image: Plot output]

Actually, I prefer the all the ticks in the form of `10^n`, and none of the commands shown above works.

Is there any simple and clever way to cope with it? I'll be grateful for your reply.

Comment: Please see [this question](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3726/125) and [Verbeia's answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/3739/125).

Comment: See also belisarius' answer to this question: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/about-number-truncation-of-ticks-display-in-listplot

Comment: I have fixed it. Thank you for your information

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Perhaps this?

```
LogPlot[Abs[BesselJ[1, x] Sin[x]^2], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{#, Superscript[10, Log10@#]} & /@ ({10^0, 10^-1, 
       10^-2, 10^-3, 10^-4, 10^-5}), None}, {None, None}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

Here's a completely different approach, manipulating the existing tick labels in the generated graph, and preserving the unlabeled ticks.  This seems much cleaner to me than Peter's approach, assuming that it works on version 8 as it does on version 7.

```
format =
  Replace[#, {p_, n_?NumericQ} :> {p, Superscript[10, Round@Log10@n]}, {#2}] &;

ticks = MapThread[format, {Options[#, {Ticks, FrameTicks}], {3, 4}}] &;
```

Use:

```
p = LogPlot[Abs[BesselJ[1, x] Sin[x]^2], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True];

Show[p, ticks[p]]
```

[image]

---

## Update 2015

#### The new Ticks subsystem

Recent versions of *Mathematica* use a different ticks rendering system wherein functions specified for `Ticks` or `FrameTicks` are passed to the Front End (which calls the Kernel) rather than being evaluated beforehand.  If we look at the options of `p` above we now see:

```
Options[p, {Ticks, FrameTicks}]
```

> ```
> {
>  Ticks -> {Automatic, Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}]}, 
>  FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], 
>     Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}]}, {Automatic, Automatic}}
> }
> ```

We could use these functions to compute tick specifications external to plotting, but to follow the spirit of the new paradigm we can modify the output of these functions instead.

`ScaledTicks` returns (at least?) three different label formats which we must handle:

```
Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}][-11.7, 1.618][[2 ;; 4, 2]] // InputForm
```

> ```
> {Superscript[10, -4], 0.001, NumberForm[0.01, {Infinity, 3}]}
> ```

The `Superscript` is already our desired format.  The other two may be handled with replacement:

```
format2 =
  Replace[#, n_?NumericQ | NumberForm[n_, _] :> Superscript[10, Round@Log10@n]] &;
```

We can then use this to apply the formatting:

```
relabel = # /. CST_Charting`ScaledTicks :> (MapAt[format2, CST[##], {All, 2}] &) &;

LogPlot[Abs[BesselJ[1, x] Sin[x]^2], {x, -10, 10}] // relabel
```

[image]

`relabel` also works with framed plots.

#### Spelunking internal functions

One may be interested is the source of the original label formatting.  `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` calls:

```
Charting`SimplePadding
```

which takes the option `"CutoffExponent"` which we would like to use, but unfortunately `ScaledTicks` overrides it.  If we use:

```
ClearAttributes[Charting`ScaledTicks, {Protected, ReadProtected}]
```

And then modify the definition to replace:

```
"CutoffExponent" -> 
 If[{Visualization`Utilities`ScalingDump`f, 
    Visualization`Utilities`ScalingDump`if} === {Identity, Identity}, 6, 4]
```

With:

```
"CutoffExponent" -> 1
```

We will find that the desired formatting has been effected:

```
LogPlot[Abs[BesselJ[1, x] Sin[x]^2], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True]
```

[image]

This modification is inadvisable however, and sadly `` Charting`ScaledTicks `` does not itself take `"CutoffExponent"` as an option that would be passed on.  One could modify *its* definition to add this option, but it is safer to use `relabel` defined above.

Comment: Yes, it is a similiar way to mine. ``LogPlot[Abs[BesselJ[1, x] Sin[x]^2], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{{10^-#, Superscript[10, -#]} & /@ {0, 1, 2, 3, 4}, 
    None}, {None, None}}]``

Comment: could you also write how to modify the number of digits for the tick labels, for example according to `NumberForm[tick, {3, 2}]`? thanks

Comment: @Valerio I don't know exactly what you want.  Are you also working with `LogPlot` or just plain `Plot`?  Do you want to change the tick labels on both axes or just the Y axis as done here?  If you are around in the next couple of hours we could [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/2234/mathematica) about it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Hi, I was wondering if it is possible to set the number of digits in e.g. the X axis (not necessarily only for LogPlot)

Comment: @Valerio you can manually specify which ticks to use with the `Ticks` or `FrameTicks` option.  You can also define a function that generates these ticks, for example: `tf = N@FindDivisions[{#, #2}, 20] &;
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, Ticks -> tf]` -- this can be done for each axis independently.  Be aware with my example that `FindDivisions` will generate *about* the number of divisions you specify and not that number exactly.

Comment: @Kuba No, it is not.  Ticks rendering has been moved to the front end and works differently now.  I'll see if I can provide a new method.  Remind me in a few days if I forget, please?

Comment: @Kuba Please see the update.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I see, thanks :) can't vote more unfortunately :)

Comment: I'm always amused by how long it takes someone to find and expertly use the internal functions. +1

Comment: @rcollyer I am not sure how to interpret that comment.  Are you saying that this has taken too long, or the opposite?

Comment: the opposite. Usually, something is released, and over time the internal functions are hunted down, tagged, and added to personal libraries, and it usually doesn't take to long. I find it impressive.

Comment: @rcollyer By the way could you use any influence you have to try to make `"CutoffExponent"` a user-settable option?  The functionality is already there, it just needs to be revealed.  I mean I want `LogPlot[. . . Method -> {"CutoffExponent" -> 1}]` or similar to work.

Comment: I can see what I can do. It's an undocumented function, in an internal context, so I don't know how much can be done.

Comment: I just saw the edit, interesting idea.

Comment: @rcollyer Any news regarding this?

Comment: As far as I am aware, they have not been documented.

Comment: @rcollyer Did you pass along my idea of `Method -> {"CutoffExponent" -> 1}`?  Was it met with outright disapproval?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know to what extent it has been looked at.

Comment: @rcollyer Thanks.

Comment: Is there any chance of applying this to x-axis as well?

Comment: @leosenko I believe it already works as written, e.g. `LogLogPlot[{x^2, x^3, x^4, x^5}, {x, 1/10, 10^4}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions"] // relabel`.  Which version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, I cannot verify whether it works on `LogLogPlot` as Mathematica places the scientific form automatically but I tried to apply it to `Plot` and while y-axis gets reformatted properly, x-axis stays the same in decimal number format. I was assuming that as the `Options` of `Plot` are the same as the `Options` of `LogLogPlot`, it would work for Plot as well

Comment: @leosenko On my system (v10.1.0 under Windows) `LogLogPlot` *does not* place all labels in scientific form.  Without `relabel`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/JQRw6.png.  With `relabel`: http://i.stack.imgur.com/CqsXJ.png.  My `relabel` function is written to work with log axes only, as it replaces ``Charting`ScaledTicks``.  Please give me an example of the kind of plot you are working with and an exact description of the labels you desire.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard a simplest example would be:
`f[x_] := 10^-16 x^-5/(Exp[5 10^-5/x]);
Plot[f[x], {x, 10^-8, 10^-4}, PlotRange -> Full]`
or similarly:
`f[x_] := 10^-16 x^-5/(Exp[5 10^-5/x]);
LogPlot[f[x], {x, 10^-8, 10^-4}, PlotRange -> Full]`

Comment: @leosenko But what would the tick labels be?  By the formula in this answer we would get http://i.stack.imgur.com/cXXtA.png but that doesn't seem useful to me, which is why I didn't include such ranges in my reasoning.  I presume you have a *different* labeling scheme in mind so that most of the *x* labels are not 10^-4?

Answer (score 23):

If you want the minor ticks too, you can use the following function:

```
SetAttributes[dtZahl, Listable]
dtZahl[x_] := Block[{n}, If[IntegerQ[n = Rationalize[x]], n, x]]

exponentForm[x_?NumberQ] := 
  Module[{me = MantissaExponent[x], num, exp}, 
   If[MemberQ[{0, 0., 1, 1., -1, -1.}, x], Return[IntegerPart[x]]];
   exp = Superscript["\[CenterDot]10", me[[2]] - 1];
   num = NumberForm[N[me[[1]]]*10 // dtZahl, 3];
   If[me[[1]] == 0.1,(*no mantissa*)num = "";
    exp = Superscript[10, me[[2]] - 1], 
    If[me[[2]] == 1,(*range 0..10*)exp = ""]];
   Row[{num, exp}]];
exponentForm[x_] := x

Options[logTicks] = {TicksFaktor -> 1};
logTicks[von_Integer, bis_Integer, werte_List, subwerte_List, 
  OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[{mt, st, ticks, res, tf},
  tf = OptionValue[TicksFaktor];
  mt = {#, exponentForm[N[#]], {0.01, 0}*tf} & /@ 
    Flatten@Table[10^i*werte, {i, von, bis}];
  st = {#, Null, {0.005, 0}*tf} & /@ 
    Flatten@Table[10^i*subwerte, {i, von, bis}];
  Join[mt, st]]
```

logTicks takes the following Parameters:
von and bis are the lowest and highest exponent. The list `werte` is the list of labeled ticks in one decade and `subwerte` the list of unlabeled ticks in one decade.

Example:

```
GraphicsRow[{
  ticks = logTicks[-4, 1, {1}, {2, 3, 5, 7}];
  LogPlot[Abs[BesselJ[1, x] Sin[x]^2], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{ticks, None}, {None, None}}],
  ticks = logTicks[-4, 1, {1, 3}, {2, 5, 7}];
  LogPlot[Abs[BesselJ[1, x] Sin[x]^2], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, 
   FrameTicks -> {{ticks, None}, {None, None}}]
  }]
```

Output:
[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: +1 very nice function! Don't know why this tick feature is still missing in MMA9...

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any simple and clever way to cope with it?

Why yes there is, just use the [`CustomTicks`](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/) package,

```
Needs@"CustomTicks`";
Plot[Log10@Abs[BesselJ[1, x] Sin[x]^2], {x, -10, 10}, Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{LogTicks, None}, {None, None}}, Axes -> None]
```

[image]

Comment: It is better to use updated version of the ``CustomTicks`` package from the [``SciDraw`` package](http://scidraw.nd.edu/) instead of the vastly outdated version available from [library.wolfram.com](http://library.wolfram.com).

Comment: @AlexeyPopkov I will check which version I have, they should take the trouble to update the post on the library though since it is the top google search result.is