# How to express ticks in scientific form?

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to express the ticks in scientific form. I tried two ways as following

```
ListLogPlot[Table[{x, 10^x}, {x, -1, 1}], Ticks -> {Automatic, {10^-1, 10^0, 10^1}}]

ListLogPlot[Table[{x, 10^x}, {x, -1, 1}],  
                          Ticks -> {Automatic, ScientificForm[{10^-1, 10^0, 10^1}]}]
```

[image]

but they just could not work as you can see; the latter even is wrong.

Why & how?

**Edit** by @belisarius

[Scientific Notation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation#Examples) is usually understood as ${1.\times 10^{-2}}$, however the OP wants just ${10^{-2}}$. Solutions for both cases can be found in the answers below.

Comment: I believe this is a duplicate but as my vote is binding I shall hold it for the time being: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5369/121

Comment: @Mr.Wizard , thanks! I should ever find that link before; however i failed to use proper key words. Anyway, i think the command Superscript is the simplest way to fulfill my requirement.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Here's one possibility. In this case, `Superscript` provides the needed format of exponents but `Table` helps in formatting `Ticks` over sets of values.

```
ListLogPlot[Table[PartitionsQ[n], {n, 50}], 
Ticks -> {Automatic, Table[{10^k, Superscript[10, k]}, {k, -2, 5}]},
PlotRange -> {Automatic, {1/1000, 10^5}}]
```

[image: output]

Comment: So far i found the Superscript is the easiest way to realize the 10^n format, as long as one notice the code need to be the form: {position, label} as Verde also pointed out. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Thanks. Sometimes a simple approach will do the job.

Comment: I'd rather use ScientificForm: Ticks -> {Automatic, Table[{10^k, ScientificForm[10^k]}, {k, -2, 5}]}, in this case

Answer (score 15):

You need the second form for the ticks `{position, label}`.

As in

```
ListLogPlot[#, Ticks -> {Automatic, {#, ScientificForm@#} & /@ #}] &@Array[10.^# &, 10]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: wow, ur code is very simple.It seems that the decimal point is crucial. If using Array[10^# &, 10], it goes back to ordinary form. Actually here i want the form like 10^1, 10^2,... without "1.".

Answer (score 14):

I would suggest using the [`CustomTicks`](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/) package. After loading the package, you do:

```
ListPlot[Table[{x, Log10[10^x]}, {x, -1, 1, .1}], Ticks -> {Automatic, LogTicks}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can also specify to use `CustomTicks`'s linear ticks:

```
ListPlot[Table[{x,Log10[10^x]},{x,-1,1,.1}],Ticks->{LinTicks,LogTicks}]
```

which gives a slightly different result:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

There are many options in this package to modify the ticks style, spacing, etc. See the [complete user's guide](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/CustomTicksGuide.pdf).

Comment: That's powerful! I guess there would be one day i use that package for beautiful presentation.