# ListLinePlot scientific notation in y axis

Tags: plotting

I am working with mathematica 9.0 and I want to make a plot importing data from a .dat file. My issue is that I don't know how to show y axis in scientific notation. My values run from 0 to approx 4000 in the y axis.
Can anybody help me?
thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5369/about-the-number-format-in-ticks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
fakedata = Transpose[{Range[500], RandomReal[4000, {500}]}];
ListLinePlot[fakedata, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, {#, ScientificForm@#} & /@  Range[0., 4000., 1000.]}, 
 PlotRange -> {0, 4500}]
```

[image]

Comment: that doesn't work. Basically I have a .dat of 500 points and when I listlineplot it the y axis runs from 0 to 4000, and the only thing I want is to show 4x10^3 instead of 4000

Comment: @user25578, please see the updated answer...

Comment: Thank you, now the ticks are how I wanted, but now I am not able to write the axes labels

Comment: user25578, did you try something like `AxesLabel -> {"axis x", "axis y"}`?

Comment: Yes, now I've tried AxesLabel and it works. I was using   FrameLabel. It's not possible to write frame labels in scientific notation? Thank you for your help

Comment: user25578, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.

Comment: When Frame is true, it does not work.

Then, one needs to use FrameTicks, instead of Ticks.