# Frame Tick Labelling in Power Form

Tags: plotting

Hopefully a simple one for you. I would like to edit the frame ticks on my plot such that they are in "power" form. As it stands I try:

```
FrameTicks -> {{{10^-9, 10^-8, 10^-7, 10^-6, 10^-5}, None}, {Automatic, None}}
```

This seems to compile with awful fraction formatting, is there a way to format it as 10^power and keep it that way?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Ticks accept several ways of formatting. In your case I'd go for pairs of values of the form `{position, label}`. Wrap your labels in quotes, like so `{10^-9, "10^-9"}`.

Comment: [This](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5369/about-the-number-format-in-ticks) might be what you want. You could also look into the [`CustomTicks` package](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/Demos/5599/) which can be pretty useful.

Comment: Thanks both. Both solutions are great!

Comment: Shall I close this as a duplicate of [(5369)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5369/121) then?

Comment: Yes I think so, unless this thread would serve as a waypoint to the solution?

Comment: There is no "unless" as (closed) duplicates themselves serve as additional entry points for the solutions.  They are not normally deleted.