# How to label ticks in ListLogLogPlot in scientific form in MMA 10.4?

Tags: plotting, bugs, labeling, ticks, logarithmic-scale

This is a question regarding ListLogLogPlot in MMA 10.4.  *I have tried the solutions suggested in [5369](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5369/about-the-number-format-in-ticks), and they do not appear to work in MMA 10.4*, so I would be grateful if this could be considered a new question by the moderators.

Using LogPlot with no tick label formatting, one gets:

```
LogLogPlot[Log[x!+1], {x, 1, 10^5}, PlotRange -> {{.1, 10^5}, {10^-1, 10^6}}]
```

[image]

Custom labels for the ticks can be added with:

```
LogLogPlot[Log[x! + 1], {x, .1, 10^5}, PlotRange -> {{.1, 10^5}, 
  {10^-1, 10^6}}, Ticks -> {Table[{10^i, 10^Defer[Evaluate[i]]}, 
  {i, -1, 5}], Table[{10^i, 10^Defer[Evaluate[i]]}, {i, -1, 6}]}]
```

[image]

So far so good.  Now with ListLogLogPlot, and no custom tick label formating, we get:

```
plist = {#, 1. Log[#! + 1]} & /@ {.1, .5, 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 
     1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000};

ListLogLogPlot[plist, PlotRange -> {{.1, 10^5}, {10^-1, 10^6}}, 
  Joined -> True]
```

[image]

Now try the custom tick labels, identical to those used above with LogLogPlot:

```
ListLogLogPlot[plist, PlotRange -> {{.1, 10^5}, {10^-1, 10^6}}, 
  Ticks -> {Table[{10^i, 10^Defer[Evaluate[i]]}, {i, -1, 5}], 
  Table[{10^i, 10^Defer[Evaluate[i]]}, {i, -1, 6}]}, Joined -> True]
```

[image]

I have tried text labels in the {value,label} form without any luck.  Post [5369](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5369/about-the-number-format-in-ticks) suggests a hack to modify the plot after generation, also no joy.

Thanks!

**UPDATE** - Looks like this has been fixed in Mathematica 11.0.

```
ListLogLogPlot[plist, PlotRange -> {{.1, 10^5}, {10^-1, 10^6}}, 
   Ticks -> {Table[{10^i, 10^Defer[Evaluate[i]]}, {i, -1, 5}], 
   Table[{10^i, 10^Defer[Evaluate[i]]}, {i, -1, 6}]}, Joined -> True]
```

[image: ListLogLogPlot in MMA 11.0]

Comment: I see now that this is a bug in 10.4 regarding `ListLogLogPlot` rather than an intentional change.  Would you instead give me the output of `Options[ListLogLogPlot[plist, PlotRange -> {{.1, 10^5}, {10^-1, 10^6}}, 
  Joined -> True],
 {Ticks, FrameTicks}]` on your system?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard I can confirm the last plot on 10.4. Requested output is 
Ticks -> {{{-2.30259, 0.1, {0.01, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}... and FrameTicks -> {{{{-2.30259, 0.1, {0.01, 0.}, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}} ...

Comment: @Johu Thank you.  Do you mind answering a few more questions for me?  If so what is the output from `Options[
 LogLogPlot[Abs[BesselJ[1, x] Sin[x]^2], {x, 1, 10000}, Frame -> True],
 {Ticks, FrameTicks}
 ]`

Comment: @Mr.Wizard ``{Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], 
   Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}]}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], 
    Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, 
      Exp}]}, {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], 
    Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}]}}}``

Comment: @Johu Thanks, again.  FYI you need to use two backticks to open and close a code-block that itself contains backtick.  I edited your comment above (scary moderator power, I know) to correct this.  Odd that `ListLogLogPlot` does not follow the convention of all the other plots to use ``Charting`ScaledTicks`` and ``Charting`ScaledFrameTicks`` as it did in version 10.1.0, and as `LogLogPlot` still does in 10.4 from your assistance.

Comment: Unrelated comment, you could use `LogGamma`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is one way to convert the ticks into the desired format:

```
ListLogLogPlot[plist, PlotRange -> {{.1, 10^5}, {10^-1, 10^6}}, Joined -> True] /. 
 {v_, t_?NumberQ, l1_, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}} :> 
 {v, NumberForm[N@t, NumberFormat -> (Superscript[#2, #3] &), 
  ExponentFunction -> (# &)], l1, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}
```

[image: Out]

---

With ticks outside and explicitly setting the `AxesOrigin` to get axes that are more aligned:

```
f[s_Spacer | s_Superscript] := s

f[n_Real | n_Integer] := Superscript[10, Rationalize@Log10[n]]

ListLogLogPlot[plist, PlotRange -> {{.1, 10^5}, {10^-1, 10^6}}, 
  Joined -> True, AxesOrigin -> {0.1, 0.1}] /. {v_, t_, l1_, l2_} :> {v, f[t], -l1, l2}
```

[image: Out2]

Comment: Nice solution.  I like that the sub-ticks still appear.  Is it possible to reverse the tick orientation (towards the outside of the plot) for major and minor ticks with a modification of the script?

Comment: @GraphMan Orientation reversion by additional replacement: `ListLogLogPlot[plist, PlotRange -> {{.1, 10^5}, {10^-1, 10^6}}, 
   Joined -> True] /. {v_, t_?NumberQ, 
    l1_, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}} :> {v, 
    NumberForm[N@t, NumberFormat -> (Superscript[#2, #3] &), 
     ExponentFunction -> (# &)], l1, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}} /. {v_,
    t_, l1_, l2_} :> {v, t, -l1, l2}`

Comment: This solution does works only on 10.4 due to replacement rule of the form ``{v_, t_?NumberQ, l1_, {AbsoluteThickness[0.1]}}``. Is there a similar soltuion for 10.3? For information ``Options[ListLogLogPlot[plist, 
  PlotRange -> {{.1, 10^5}, {10^-1, 10^6}}, Joined -> True], {Ticks, 
  FrameTicks}]`` gives ``{Ticks -> {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], 
   Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}]}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], 
    Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, 
      Exp}]}, {Charting`ScaledTicks[{Log, Exp}], 
    Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{Log, Exp}]}}}``

Comment: @Johu Did you see the **Update 2015** section in [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5371/18476)?

Comment: `ListLogLogPlot[plist, PlotRange -> {{.1, 10^5}, {10^-1, 10^6}}, 
  Joined -> True] /. {v_, t_?NumberQ, l1_, l2_} :> {v, 
   NumberForm[N@t, NumberFormat -> (Superscript[#2, #3] &), 
    ExponentFunction -> (# &)], l1, l2}` works in version 9.

Answer (score 6):

I tested on 10.2 and 10.4. I recommend just using the tick labels from some other plot and overlaying the data using `Show`. With minimal changes to your example I got following proof of principle.

```
plist = {#, 1. Log[#! + 1]} & /@ {.1, .5, 1, 5, 10, 50, 100, 500, 
    1000, 5000, 10000, 50000, 100000};

Show[{LogLogPlot[0, {x, .1, 10^5}, 
   PlotRange -> {{.1, 10^5}, {10^-1, 10^6}}, 
   Ticks -> {Table[{10^i, 10^Defer[Evaluate[i]]}, {i, -1, 5}], 
     Table[{10^i, 10^Defer[Evaluate[i]]}, {i, -1, 6}]}], 
  ListLogLogPlot[plist, PlotRange -> {{.1, 10^5}, {10^-1, 10^6}}, 
   Joined -> True]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice!!  Thank you!!   This is much simpler and more elegant than some of the previous answers to other similar questions.  Still, it would be good if this bug was fixed so one did not have to resort to such hacks....

Comment: If you want to contribute to getting a fix turn your post into [a bug report](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tags/bugs/info) and report to WR.

Comment: Done!  Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

Using custom tick labels still works, but one has to use the logarithmic label position, as this conversion is no longer done automatically for custom tick labels.

```
ListLogLogPlot[plist, PlotRange -> {{.1, 10^5}, {10^-1, 10^6}}, 
 Ticks -> {Table[{N@Log[10^i], Superscript[10, i]}, {i, -1, 5}], 
           Table[{N@Log[10^i], Superscript[10, i]}, {i, -1, 6}]}, 
 Joined -> True]
```

[image: Out]