# Number formatting of ticks in graphs without specifying ticks explicitly

Tags: ticks

How do i use accounting form as default for ticks in graph?

I am using

```
$PrePrint=AccountingForm;
```

but this is not affecting the ticks in graph.

Michael this following is still causing problems.

```
RectangleChart[{{{1, 275223.704333`}, {1, 647056.333196`}, {1, 
    595454.512134`}, {1, 588530.099239`}}, {{1, 839132.567778`}, {1, 
    968881.133341`}, {1, 1.225078442665`*^6}, {1, 
    1.148257714327`*^6}}}, BarSpacing -> {0, 1}, 
 ChartLabels -> {Placed[{"New", "Renew"}, {0.5, 0.5}], {1, 2, 3, 4}}, 
 ChartStyle -> (Directive[#, Opacity[0.75]] & /@ 
    ColorData[97, "ColorList"]), ImageSize -> Large, Axes -> True, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 FrameTicks -> {{acctTicks, None}, {None, None}}, PlotRange -> All]
```

Comment: try something like `Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, 
 Ticks -> {{#, AccountingForm[N@#, 3]} & /@ 
    Range[-2 Pi, 2 Pi, 
     Pi/2], {#, AccountingForm[#]} & /@ {-1, -.5, .5, 1}}]`

Comment: But i am writing a general code which has to work with plots of any range. Thus would like to not specify the ticks explicitly.

Comment: Ask WRI for this feature as the more that ask the more likely it will be added. I wanted to do this a while ago and made a suggestion to WRI to add an option for axis and one for frame to both Graphics and Graphics3D (that most other plots would inherit) that takes a function to format each axis/frame. For example the option would have taken `ConstantArray[AccountingForm[#, {3,2}]&, 2]` to reformat both axis of `Plot`.

Answer (score 3):

You can define a function to post-process the plot outputs to modify the labels for `Ticks` or `FrameTicks`:

```
postProcessF = Module[{o, frame = (Frame /. Options[#, Frame])}, 
  Module[{t = If[frame === False, o = Ticks, o = FrameTicks] /. Quiet[AbsoluteOptions@#]}, 
     t[[All, All, 2]] = t[[All, All, 2]] /. x_?NumericQ :> AccountingForm[x]; 
     Show[#, Frame -> frame, o -> t]]] &;
```

Examples:

```
postProcessF @ Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
postProcessF @ Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
postProcessF @ Plot[Sin[x], {x, -2 Pi, 2 Pi}, Frame -> {{True, False}, {True, True}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: ... this does not handle the case where `Frame -> {{False, False}, {False, False}}`.

Comment: If you apply `AbsoluteOptions[#,Ticks]&` and `AbsoluteOptions[#,FrameTicks]&` on `RectangularChart` it doesn't return the ticks being used in the plot. So i don't know how to use the post-process method. Can you please make it work with `RectangularChart`.

Answer (score 1):

The methods in the Q&A, [About the number format in ticks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5369/about-the-number-format-in-ticks/5371#5371), could probably be adapted to this case.

Here's an approach, somewhat like Mr. Wizard's in the linked Q&A:

```
acctTicks = Charting`ScaledTicks[{Identity, Identity}][##] /.
  {{x_?NumericQ, Except[_Spacer], y__} :> {x, AccountingForm[x], y}} &;

Plot[1.5 Sin[x], {x, -6, 6}, Ticks -> {acctTicks, acctTicks}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[1.5 Sin[x], {x, -6, 6},
 Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{acctTicks, Automatic}, {acctTicks, Automatic}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
RectangleChart[
 {{{1, -10^8}, {2, -20^7}, {3, 3*10^8}}, {{1, -10^8}, {2, -10^9}, {3, 10^9}}}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 FrameTicks -> {{acctTicks, None}, {acctTicks, None}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: how do i load this `Charting\`ScaledTicks` function is it available to download or included in mathematica.

Comment: @user13892 It should already be included, unless you have a very old version. It's part of the support functions for `Plot` and can be found in answers on this site since 2012.  Did it not work for you?

Comment: Thank you, why it is not working in this code:

`RectangleChart[{{{1, -10^8}, {2, -20^7}, {3, 
    3*10^8}}, {{1, -10^8}, {2, -10^9}, {3, 10^9}}}, 
 PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
 FrameTicks -> {{acctTicks, None}, {acctTicks, None}}]`

Comment: I believe i will have to change the function `acctTicks` to make it work with this but i don't understand how it works.

Comment: Michael can you please write one that will work for `RectangleChart[{{{1, -10^8}, {2, -20^7}, {3, 3*10^8}}, {{1, -10^8}, {2, -10^9}, {3, 10^9}}}, PlotTheme -> "Detailed", FrameTicks -> {{acctTicks, None}, {acctTicks, None}}]`. I can't write it on my own.

Comment: You can check your `acctTicks` does not work on this and must be modified.

Comment: The *Chart family functions do many things automatically that interfere with normal plotting options.  Perhaps you'd prefer the look of this: `RectangleChart[{{{1, -10^8}, {2, -20^7}, {3, 3*10^8}}, {{1, -10^8}, {2, -10^9}, {3, 10^9}}}, ChartLabels -> {"a", "b", "c"}, Ticks -> {None, acctTicks}, Axes -> True, Frame -> False, PlotTheme -> "Detailed"]` --> http://i.stack.imgur.com/yEN2I.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/59116/discussion-between-user13892-and-michael-e2).