# Changing Y-Axis to "Billions of Dollars"

Tags: charts, units

Is there a way to change my bar chart's Y-axis from powers of 10 to "billions of dollars"?  For example `$100,000,000,000` should read as `$100B` instead of `1 x 10^11` of dollars.

```
BarChart[<|"Bridgewater AUM" ->$ 1 10^11,"Softbank Vision Fund" -> $ 1 10^11|>, Frame->True, PlotLabel->"Assets Under Management", FrameLabel->Automatic, ChartLabels->Automatic, ImageSize->700, TargetUnits->"Dollars"]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Consider using `` Charting`FindTicks `` to avoid manually specifying the plot range.

```
billionticks = 
  Map[ Replace[{n_, lbl_} :> {n, If[n == 0, 0, Row[{"$", lbl/1*^9, "B"}]]}] ] @* 
    Charting`FindTicks[{0, 1}, {0, 1}];

BarChart[<|"Bridgewater AUM" -> 1 10^11, "Softbank Vision Fund" -> 1 10^11|>, 
 Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> {{billionticks, Automatic}, Automatic}, 
 PlotLabel -> "Assets Under Management", FrameLabel -> Automatic, 
 ChartLabels -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 400, TargetUnits -> "Dollars"]
```

[image]

Related: [About the number format in ticks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5369/121)

Answer (score 2):

You may use the [Units & Quantities](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/Units.html) metric conversions.

The quantity system understands [metric prefixes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix), for example `"Centi"` and `"Mega"`.  Therefore you can use [`TargetUnits`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/TargetUnits.html) if you have [`Quantity`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Quantity.html) objects for it to convert.

A billion in metric prefix is a `"Giga"`.  Either the unitless quantity `"Unities"` or a specific currency like `"USDollars"` can be used.

Let

```
aum =  <|"Bridgewater AUM" -> 1 10^11, "Softbank Vision Fund" -> 1 10^11|>;
```

Then with  `"Unities"`

```
BarChart[Quantity[aum, "Unities"],
 Frame -> True, 
 PlotLabel -> "Assets Under Management",
 FrameLabel -> {Automatic, "Billions $"},
 ChartLabels -> Automatic,
 ImageSize -> 700,
 TargetUnits -> "Giga"]
```

and with currency `"USDollars"`

```
BarChart[Quantity[aum, "USDollars"],
 Frame -> True, 
 PlotLabel -> "Assets Under Management",
 FrameLabel -> {Automatic, "Billions $"},
 ChartLabels -> Automatic,
 ImageSize -> 700,
 TargetUnits -> "Giga*USDollars"]
```

Both produce the following chart.

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Hope this helps.

PS: You can also us syntax like `"Giga" "USDollars"` or `"Giga"*"USDollars"` instead of all in on string.

Answer (score 1):

```
yTicks = {#*10^10, If[Mod[#, 2] == 0, "$" <> ToString[10 #] <> "B", ""]} &/@ Range[0, 10, 2];

BarChart[<|"Bridgewater AUM" -> 1 10^11, "Softbank Vision Fund" -> 1 10^11|>, Frame -> True, 
PlotLabel -> "Assets Under Management", FrameLabel -> Automatic,
 FrameTicks -> {{yTicks, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}, 
 ChartLabels -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 700, TargetUnits -> "Dollars"]
```

To get the small ticks you can adjust the stepsize in `Range` the way you prefer.