# How to display order of magnitude for ticks in ListLogPlot?

Tags: plotting, ticks, notation

I have tried many ways of doing this, but cannot figure out what mathematica wants me to do to make it work. The simplest example of what I want to do is this, I want to change the vertical axis to display ticks 10^-4, 10^-3, 10^-2, 10^-1, 10^0 instead of the mixed scientific form and decimal form that mathematica decides that I want. I have tried defining the ticks or frame ticks and usually it either has no effect on the plot whatsoever or it removes the minor ticks which is something I want.

This is the example:
ListLogPlot[MultDistHist, PlotRange -> {{0, 6}, {10^-4, 10^0}}]
[image]

Comment: Found the answer here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5369/about-the-number-format-in-ticks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [About the number format in ticks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5369/about-the-number-format-in-ticks)