# Adapt ticks in plot and font in legend

Tags: graphics, legending

Some of my 2-dimensional data are displayed with a code similar to this:

```
Needs["PlotLegends`"]
sampleData = 
Transpose[{RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 3*10^-6], 20000], 
RandomVariate [NormalDistribution[0, 3*10^-6], 20000]}]; 
binning = {{-1*10^-5, 1*10^-5, 1*10^-7}, {-1*10^-5, 1*10^-5,1*10^-7}};
(*binning of my sampleData*)
maxBinnedData=Max[HistogramList[sampleData,binning][[2]]];
(*seachring for the maximum of the binned data*)
ShowLegend[DensityHistogram[sampleData,binning,LabelingFunction->None,
PerformanceGoal->"Speed", 
ColorFunction->(If[1-#1===0,White,ColorData["Rainbow"][#1]]&),
ColorFunctionScaling->True,PlotRange->{{-1*10^-5, 1*10^-5},{-1*10^-5, 1*10^-5}}, 
FrameLabel->{"x", "y"},
LabelStyle->Directive[Black,FontSize->12,FontFamily->"Arial"],ImageSize->{500,500}],{(If[1-#1===0,White,ColorData["Rainbow"][1-#1]]&),11,
ToString[maxBinnedData],ToString[0],LegendTextOffset->{-2, 0},
LegendPosition->{1.1,-0.4},LegendShadow->None,
LegendLabel->Style["Counts",Black,FontSize->12,FontFamily->"Arial"]}]
```

The output is quite nice for my taste (see figure).[image: Output of my code]

Yet, I want to improve two things, but all my attempts have been unsuccessfully so far.

First: How can I manage that the ticks are all in scientific form (e.g. $1.0\times10^{-5}$ instead of 0.00001)?
Somehow I was not able to adapt the tricks of e.g. [this post](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3726/listloglinearplot-logarithmic-axis-tickmarks) to my problem. I could do it perhaps by hand, but the scale is often different (e.g. from $-2.4 \times 10^{-5}$ to $4.0 \times 10^{-6}$) so that this will be unhandy.

Second: As perhaps can be seen, I try to use for all names and numbers the `FontSize->12` and the `FontFamily->“Arial”`. That works fine except for the numbers in my legend (0 and 20). How do I have to change the font setting there? I tried things like `Style[ToString[maxBinnedData], Black, FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Arial"]` instead of `ToString[maxBinnedData]` but nothing worked.

I would be happy if some people here could give me some hints!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

For the first part of your question, you can specify a function for the `FrameTicks` or `Ticks` option. This function will then be applied to `xmin` and `xmax` (or `ymin` and `ymax` for the tick marks along the vertical axis). This means that you can let this function take care of the placement of the tick marks automatically without having to worry about different plot ranges. For example, you could do something like

```
ticks[ndiv_Integer: 5, nsubdiv_Integer: 5, 
   label_: (ScientificForm[N[#], 3] &)][xmin_, xmax_] := 
 With[{div = FindDivisions[{xmin, xmax}, {ndiv, nsubdiv}], 
   labelf = If[label === None, ("" &), label]},
  Join[{#, labelf[#], {0.01, 0}} & /@ div[[1]], 
    {#, "", {.00625, 0}} & /@ Flatten[div[[2, All, 2 ;; -2]]]]]
```

Here, `ndiv` is the (approximate) number of major tick marks, `nsubdiv` the number of subdivisions between the the major tick marks, and `label` a function for specifying the formatting the tick labels. I've chosen `label` to be equal to `ScientificForm[N[#], 3] &` by default. You can also specify `None` if you don't want tick labels.

**Usage**

For the plot above, you would get something like

```
pl = DensityHistogram[sampleData, binning, LabelingFunction -> None, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", 
  ColorFunction -> (If[1 - #1 === 0, White, 
      ColorData["Rainbow"][#1]] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1.024*10^-5, 1*10^-5}, {-1*10^-5, 1*10^-5}}, 
  FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Arial"], 
  ImageSize -> {500, 500}];

Show[pl, FrameTicks -> {{ticks[], ticks[None]}, {ticks[], ticks[None]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edit**

To change the style of the numbering in the legend, you could use the `BaseStyle` option (in `ShowLegend`), for example

```
With[{label = ticks[(If[# === 0, 0, ScientificForm[N[#], 3]] &)]},
 ShowLegend[
  Show[pl, FrameTicks -> {{label, ticks[None]}, {label, ticks[None]}}], 
   {(If[1 - #1 === 0, White, ColorData["Rainbow"][1 - #1]] &), 11,
   ToString[maxBinnedData], 
   ToString[0], LegendTextOffset -> {-1.3, 0}, 
   LegendPosition -> {1.1, -0.4},
   LegendShadow -> None,
   LegendLabel -> Style["Counts", Black, FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Arial"],
   BaseStyle -> {FontFamily -> "Arial", FontSize -> 12}
   }]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that I also got rid of the dot at 0. by using a slightly different function for typesetting the tick labels in `ticks`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for both answers (Heike and @belisarius). Both are working fine. If I use e.g. `ShowLegend[Show[hist, FrameTicks -> s1],{rest of my code}]`, I have even the legend again.
Now I hope that somebody can help me with the second question.
By the way, although it is not really important for me, how could I get rid of the dot at 0.?

Comment: @partial81 I've updated my answer

Comment: Dear @Heike, Thanks for editing your post! Now I have the plot I wanted to have. With your solution and with a bit of work, it is even easy to have e.g. for the x-axis scientific notation and for the y-axis the number form. Additionally, I can change the ticks lengths! That is really a nice addition! Not to forget that you got rid of the dot at the 0.! Thanks for this great help!

Answer (score 5):

For your first question:

```
sampleData = Transpose[{RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 3*10^-6], 200], 
                        RandomVariate[NormalDistribution[0, 3*10^-6], 200]}]; 
hist = 
 DensityHistogram[sampleData, binning, LabelingFunction -> None, 
  PerformanceGoal -> "Speed", ColorFunction -> (If[1 - #1 === 0, White, 
      ColorData["Rainbow"][#1]] &), ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1*10^-5, 1*10^-5}, {-1*10^-5, 1*10^-5}},    FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Arial"], 
  ImageSize -> {500, 500}];

binning = {{-1*10^-5, 1*10^-5, 1*10^-6}, {-1*10^-5, 1*10^-5, 1*10^-6}};
(*binning of my sampleData*)
maxBinnedData = Max[HistogramList[sampleData, binning][[2]]];

(*Here comes the trick*)
s = AbsoluteOptions[hist, FrameTicks] /. {o_ -> s_List} :> s;
s1 = s /. {v__, w__, h__, j__} :> {(MapAt[ScientificForm, #, {2}] & /@  v), 
                                   (MapAt[ScientificForm, #, {2}] & /@ w), h, j};
Show[hist, FrameTicks -> s1]
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @belisarius, Thanks for solving the first part of my question. The second part was well answered from Heike, and halirutan has given a nice solution too.

Answer (score 4):

You could do everything in post-processing by replacing parts of your output graphics. Your "Arial"-problem seems to come from some strange behavior inside the `` PlotLegends` `` package which does not let you give `Style`-ized text. Here you can simply replace every `Text`-directive which does not use style. The rule for that looks lik

```
rule1 = Text[str_String, rest___] :> 
        Text[Style[str, FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Arial"], rest]
```

`rest` (and all the rests I'll use later) are always some parameters/options which may or may not follow and which I simply append again.

For the replacement-rule of the `FrameTicks` you have to inspect the final graphics a bit, because `ShowLegend` includes your original plot as `Inset` in the final `Graphics`. Therefore, I replace the graphics in the first `Inset` by the same graphics with altered `FrameTicks`. For this I extract with `AbsoluteOptions` the values for the ticks and wrap `ScientificForm` around. With this information even the slightly complex rule should be readable

```
rule2 = Graphics[{Inset[densGr_, rest1___], rest2___}, rest3___] :> 
 Graphics[{Inset[
    densGr /. (FrameTicks -> _) -> 
      (FrameTicks -> Last@Last[(AbsoluteOptions[densGr, FrameTicks] /. 
        {a_?NumericQ, b_?NumericQ, c_List, d_List} :> 
        {a, ScientificForm[b], c, d})]), 
     rest1], 
   rest2}, rest3]
```

Finally, you just have to use these replacement rules with your graphics, which I called `gr` here

```
gr /. rule1 /. rule2
```

[image]

Comment: Dear @halirutan, Thanks for this easy solution. It is almost as good as the one from Heike! I really appreciate that you showed a totally different way to get almost the same desired plot!