# Dates as FrameTicks on a ListLinePlot

Tags: plotting, graphics

For reasons too lengthy to explain, I would like to display a list of dates or years (as numbers or strings) as `FrameTicks` on a `ListLinePlot`.

An example of what I have so far follows:

```
xle = FinancialData["XLE", All];
DateListPlot[xle, ImageSize -> 350]
ListLinePlot[xle[[All, 2]], ImageSize -> 350]
firstDateByYear = First /@ SplitBy[xle[[All, 1]], #[[1]] &]
positions = Flatten[Position[xle[[All, 1]], #] & /@ firstDateByYear]
years= firstDateByYear[[All,1]]
```

[image: Plots]

```
{{1998, 12, 22}, {1999, 1, 4}, {2000, 1, 3}, {2001, 1, 2}, {2002, 1, 2},{2003, 1, 2}, {2004, 1, 2}, {2005, 1, 3}, {2006, 1, 3}, {2007, 1, 3}, {2008, 1, 2}, {2009, 1, 2}, {2010, 1, 4}, {2011, 1, 3}, {2012, 1, 3}}

{1, 8, 260, 512, 760, 1012, 1264, 1516, 1768, 2019, 2270, 2523, 2775, 3027, 3279}

{1998, 1999, 2000, 2001, 2002, 2003, 2004, 2005, 2006, 2007, 2008, 2009, 2010, 2011, 2012}
```

I thought that identifying a position at which I wanted to place a label would help.

The following earlier question [Formatting Ticks and FrameTicks labels with a function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6851/formatting-ticks-and-frameticks-labels-with-a-function) relates to what I want to do, but I haven't understood it sufficiently to adapt it to my needs.

Doing something like placing a string for the year at every other position in the list "positions" would give me a clear idea of how to do more complicated things on my own.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You got very close to the solution: you simply have to pair up the positions and the year values, and feed it to the bottom FrameTicks specification (as in `FrameTicks->{{left, right}, {bottom, top}}`). I've filtered the years to only display those that are multiples of 5. Note however that this method of year & position extraction works only if the curated financial data is continuous (i.e. there are no gaps of date).

```
xle = FinancialData["XLE", All];

years = xle[[All, 1, 1]];
pos = Flatten[Position[years, #, 1, 1] & /@ Union@years];
ticks = Thread@{pos, Union@years};
filteredTicks = Cases[ticks, _?(Mod[Last@#, 5] == 0 &)];

DateListPlot[xle, ImageSize -> 350]
ListLinePlot[xle[[All, 2]], ImageSize -> 350, Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> False, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {filteredTicks, None}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Thanks for the quick solution and insights into uses of Union and Thread I don't usually think about.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly using `ListLinePlot` instead of `DateListPlot` is a good choice. You will find it much faster.

```
xle = FinancialData["XLE", All];

AbsoluteTiming[DateListPlot[xle, ImageSize -> 350];]
{0.438556, Null}

AbsoluteTiming[ListLinePlot[xle[[All, 2]], ImageSize -> 350];]
{0.021308, Null}
```

So 20 times faster but of course you need to process the ticks. For regular data István Zachar's solution will be fastest. On my machine 0.027.

For irregular data you will need to work with `AbsoluteTimes`. Incidentally you will find `DateListPlot` works faster if you first convert to `AbsoluteTime` (even taking into account the time taken for this conversion). Typically rendering time will be halved.

So the method below will work for irregular intervals and is still about 5 times faster than `DateListPlot` (on my machine).

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 xle1 = xle;
 xle1[[All, 1]] = AbsoluteTime /@ xle[[All, 1]];
 years = Range[xle[[1, 1, 1]], xle[[-1, 1, 1]]];
 absYears = AbsoluteTime /@ Thread[{years, 1, 1}];
 interval = 5;
 selector = Boole[Thread[Mod[years, interval] == 0]];
 ticks = DeleteCases[
   Transpose[{selector*absYears, selector*years}], {0, 0}];

(* or if you minor ticks then uncomment this
ticks = Transpose[{absYears, selector*years}] /. 0 -> ""; *)

 ListLinePlot[xle1, ImageSize -> 350, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {ticks, None}}]]

{0.08415, Null}
```

Incidentally I use `ListLinePlot` for dynamic plotting such as this

[image]

because it updates much faster than `DateListPlot`.

Comment: I hadn't thought about the timing issue.  Very helpful insight.  Thx

Comment: No worries. Note that for financial data you will need to use this approach if you want accurate ticks because exchanges are not open on new years day.