# Change only tick labels while keeping default ticks

Tags: plotting

Consider the following `Plot3D` (although the same question might be asked for the 2D case)

```
Plot3D[Sin[x + y^2], {x, -3, 3}, {y, -2, 2}]
```

[image: 3D plot]

How can I replace the tick labels on the, let's say, x and y axes while keeping the default major and minor ticks (positions and format)?

Rephrased: How can I change the tick labels without changing anything else?

The *Mathematica* help for `Ticks` shows an example that replaces the major ticks and assigns new labels, but in doing so (specifying all ticks explicitly) looses the minor ticks.