# Simple reformatting of the ticks in a plot

Tags: plotting, ticks

I often deal with graphs involving large dollar amounts over time. Mathematica will generally format Y-axis ticks as scientific numbers `{1.0x10^6, 1.2x10^6 . . . etc.}`.

So for example,

```
mydata = EventSeries@
  Table[{DatePlus[DateObject[{2010, 1, 1}], {x, "Month"}], 
    10^6 RandomReal[{1, 2}]}, {x, 0, 20}];

myplot = DateListPlot[mydata]
```

I'm happy to let Mathematica pick where the ticks go, but I want to change the formatting to `{$1.0MM, $1.2MM . . . etc.}`.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Comment: Try [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/87300/9490)

Answer (score 2):

Some fake data:

```
mydata = Table[{x, 10^6 RandomReal[{1, 2}]}, {x, 0, 1, .05}];
```

A plot with traditional (undesired) ordinate ticks:

```
myplot = ListPlot[mydata];
```

Old ordinate tick data extracted from `myplot`:

```
ordinateticks = (Ticks /. AbsoluteOptions[myplot, Ticks])[[2]];
```

Scaled and relabeled ordinate ticks:

```
myticks2 = MapAt[
  If[# != "",
    ("$" <> ToString[N[#/10^6, 2]] <> "MM")] &, ordinateticks, {All, 2}]
```

Replot of `mydata` with the new ordinate ticks:

```
ListPlot[mydata, Ticks-> {Automatic, myticks2}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you but this does not work for Date/Data pairs as in my new example above. How might this approach be adapted for `DateListPlot[]`s?

Comment: I urge you to ask your *actual* question (which did not originally include Date/Data pairs), otherwise we answerers are wasting our time.

Comment: My apologies; it honestly did not occur to me that the answer would be different for TimeSeries data.