# Changing the y-axis tick style of a RegionPlot

Tags: plotting, style

I have an inequality of the form $f(x,y) < 1$ and plot it with

```
RegionPlot[f[x, y] < 1, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 10^-7, 10^-4}]
```

The y-axis ticks are displayed as 0.000001 and so on. How can I change the tick style to display them as 10^-6 and so on?

Comment: it seems there is a typo in your code. it should be `{x,0,5}` ,not `{0,x,5}`

Comment: @Alucard :  thank you, I've corrected.

Comment: Have you seen [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5369/about-the-number-format-in-ticks) and [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3726/listloglinearplot-logarithmic-axis-tickmarks/3739#3739)?