# About number truncation of ticks display in ListPlot

Tags: plotting, options

In my problem, I need to plot a figure in a relatively small region of the $x$ axis, e.g.,

```
 ListPlot[{RandomReal[#] + 10^4, 
   RandomReal[#]} & /@ (Range[100] 10^-10), Frame -> True, Axes -> False]
```

and the figure is displayed properly, but all the tick marks have the same label:

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Is there any clever way to get rid of this problem?

Comment: 欢迎来到Mathematica.SE!  :-)  Don't worry about image uploading, you'll soon have enough reputation to do it.  Until then we'll help you.  Please make sure to include the question in the body of the post as well (not only in the title).  A little redundancy doens't help

Comment: Oh great! I think U know well about Chinese language, SZabolcs.

Comment: Related: [(3436)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3436/121)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can define your own function for `FrameTicks` :

```
ticks[min_, max_] := {#, NumberForm[#, 20]} & /@ 
  N[FindDivisions[{min, max}, 5]]

ListPlot[{RandomReal[#] + 10^4, 
    RandomReal[#]} & /@ (Range[100] 10^-10), Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {ticks, None}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Just choose your own preferred presentation format of the given values...

```
ticks[min_, max_] := {#, Grid[{{min}, {"+"}, {# - min}}]} & /@ 
  N[FindDivisions[{min, max}, 5]]

ListPlot[{RandomReal[#] + 10^4, 
    RandomReal[#]} & /@ (Range[100] 10^-10), Frame -> True, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, {ticks, None}},FrameStyle->Medium]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Excellent work!!

Answer (score 7):

```
ListPlot[{RandomReal[#] + 10^4, RandomReal[#]} & /@ (Range[100] 10^-10), Frame -> True, 
          Axes -> False, FrameLabel -> {"x - 10^4", "y"}] /. 
          List[x_, y_] /; x > 10000 -> List[x - 10000, y]
```

[image]

Comment: i'm sure it'a a way to solve it.