# Y-axis Tick labels are all identical

Tags: plotting

For `Plot[x^12 - x^9 + x^4 + 1, {x, -.001, .001}]`
[image]

Details on Y-axis seem to be wrong.I am using V 9.0.1.0 .Bug?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This function is set up so that the relative difference between the values is tiny.   Just look at the average value of the function over the range, versus the variation,

```
Differences@(Function[x, x^12 - x^9 + x^4 + 1] /@ {.001, 0.005, 0.0})
Mean@(Function[x, x^12 - x^9 + x^4 + 1] /@ {.001, 0.005, 0.0})
(* {6.24*10^-10, -6.25*10^-10} *)
(* 1. *)
```

Even scientific notation isn't going to save you here since you need a large number of digits to see the differences.  So just adapt [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/5277/9490) to suit your problem,

```
ticks[min_, max_] := {#, NumberForm[#, {20, 15}]} & /@ 
  N[FindDivisions[{min, max}, 5]]

Plot[(x^12 - x^9 + x^4 + 1), {x, -.001, .001}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, ticks}]
```

[image]

Or better yet, something like this,

```
Plot[(x^12 - x^9 + x^4 + 1) - 1, {x, -.001, .001}, Axes -> False, 
 Frame -> True, FrameLabel -> {"x", "f(x)-1"}]
```

[image]