# Dollar Signs in Tick Marks

Tags: graphics

I want to display one axis using dollar amounts in the tickmarks (as "$500"). Searched the documentation but I cannot see `AccountingForm` doing that and I am stuck.

Comment: `Ticks` should see you right. This answer: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5276/131 should be adaptable.

Comment: Not that I can tell.`Ticks -> {NumberForm[{0, 500, 1000}, NumberSigns -> {"-$", "$"}], 
  Automatic}` produces an error.

Comment: I used this as a workaround, but it seems embarassingly elaborate. I define a pair of values and same with the dollar sign prepended: `tks = Table[{i, NumberForm[i, NumberSigns -> {"-$", "$"}]}, {i, 0, 
   1000, 500}]` and then inside the graph `Ticks -> {tks, Automatic}`.

Comment: Adding a working, self-contained example may help getting more help. Your fix does not seem too bad though, if you are happy with the results.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I figured it out, adapting it from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5276/about-number-truncation-of-ticks-display-in-listplot):

Define a tick function using minimum and maximum:

```
dollarticks[min_, max_] := {#, NumberForm[#, NumberSigns -> {"-$", "$"}]} & /@ N[FindDivisions[{min, max}, 3]]
```

Then use that in the graph with:

```
Ticks -> {dollarticks, Automatic}
```

Quod erat demonstrandum.

Then I developed a fuller version, that drops the trailing period signifying [working precision?]. First define a function that can also be used by itself in a tick specification:

```
adollartick[x_] := {x,
  If[Round[x]==x,(*is the rightmost character a period, 
   from some precision?*)
   NumberForm[Round@x, NumberSigns -> {"-$", "$"}, 
      DigitBlock -> 3](*put dollar sign and comma and use Round to drop the last digit*)
   ,(*else*)
   NumberForm[x, NumberSigns -> {"-$", "$"}, 
    DigitBlock -> 3](*just put dollar sign and comma*)
   ]}
```

and then define the function for putting few dollar ticks:

```
dollarticks[min_, max_] := adollartick[#] & /@ 
  N[FindDivisions[{min, max}, 
    3]](*to produce dollar amounts as tick marks with few tickmarks*)
```

or many

```
dollarticks7[min_, max_] := 
 adollartick[#] & /@ 
  N[FindDivisions[{min, max}, 
    7]](*to produce dollar amounts as tick marks with more tickmarks*)
```

While we are at it, do the same for percentage ticks:

```
apercenttick[x_] := {x, If[
    Round[100 x] == 100 x,(*is rightmost a period?*)
    ToString[Round[100 x]],(*then drop it by using Round*)
    ToString[100 x]](*else just multily by 100*)
   <> "%"}(*and append a % sign*)

percentticks[min_, max_] := apercenttick[#]& /@ N[FindDivisions[{min, max}, 7]]
```

Comment: Great that you posted a self-answer! Nitpicking: quod... https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q.E.D.