# manipulating the X axis notation in mathematica graph

Tags: plotting

I plotted a graph in mathematica that displays the function

```
M/1480 = (4*Pi*G*r)/(3c^2)  R^3
```

here ,

```
G=6.67*10^-11
r=10^18
c=2.997*10^8
```

I got the graph where R in the X axis shows the notation in meters, such as 4000, 8000, 10000 etsc. how can I give an instruction to mathematica so that it appears in km so that i get 4, 8 , 10 km in X axis..

A complete instruction to plot the graph is needed.

Comment: Try [UnitConvert](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/UnitConvert.html), e.g.. `UnitConvert[Quantity[10^7,"Meters"],"Kilometers"]`

Comment: Welcome. Please supply the code you used so far.

Comment: see also this Q/A: [Number format of axes in a plot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3436/125)

Answer (score 1):

If your x-axis data (first column in your data matrix) is in the form `100000 m`, as in the following fake data

```
dt1a = Sort@ Transpose[{Quantity[RandomInteger[10^4, 100], "Meter"], RandomReal[100, 100]}];
```

then you can use `UnitConvert` on the first column of your data:

```
dt1b = MapAt[UnitConvert[#, "Kilometer"] &, dt2, {All, 1}];
```

Plotting the two data sets side by side

```
llp1a = ListLinePlot[dt2a, ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True];
llp1b = ListLinePlot[dt2b, ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True];
Row[{llp2, llp2b}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Alternatively, you can use `FrameTicks` or `Ticks` (depending on whether have a Frame in your plot) to format the tick labels as follows:

```
dt2 = Sort@Transpose[{RandomInteger[10^4, 100], RandomReal[100, 100]}];

llp2a = ListLinePlot[dt2, ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True];
llp2b = ListLinePlot[dt2, ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True,
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic,  None}, 
                  {{#, #/1000} & /@ Range[0, 10000, 1000], None}}];
llp2c = ListLinePlot[dt2, ImageSize -> 300, Frame -> True,
   FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, None}, 
                  {{#, Row[{#/1000, " km"}]} & /@ Range[0, 10000, 1000],  None}}];
Row[{llp2a, llp2b, llp2c}, Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Related Q/As: [Number format of axes in a plot](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/3436/125)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to change the x-ticks. In your case, the most simple solution is probably scaling the function and not touching the tick labels at all. Plot, hence, `(4*\pi Gr)/(3c^2) (1000*R)` with $x$ running from $x_\text{Min}/1000$ to $x_\text{Max}/1000$

You can directly manipulate what Mathematica is placing as label

```
plf=FullGraphics[Plot[ (4 Pi G r)/(3 c^2) R,{R,0,100000},Frame->True]];
Show[plf/.Text[x_,y__]/;IntegerQ[x] -> Text[x/1000,y],AspectRatio-> 1]
```

By using FullGraphics[] all plot commands a made explicit, i.e. the ticks are explicitly Line[] command and the labels are Text[] commands. The Replace[], i.e. `/.` looks for text which has an integer argument and replaces it by text at the same position with a label `1000` times smaller. This works in my case as y labels are floating point. Depending on your plot details you might need to modify the condition between `/;` and `->`.

And finally you can tell Mathematica what to put as label

```
Plot[ (4 Pi G r)/(3 c^2) R,{R,0,100000},Frame->True,
FrameTicks->{
Table[If[Mod[i,20000]==0, {i,i/1000,{.01,0}},
{i,"",{.005,0}}],{i,0,100000,5000}],Automatic,Automatic,Automatic
}]
```

This puts the ticks on y (left and right) as well as on top automatically. Your x-Ticks are placed every `5000` as minor and every `20000` as major tick. You might want to change the length though, i.e. the `.01` and `.005`
Note, if you do not use Frame it is `Ticks` and not `FrameTicks`