# How to rotate TickMarks in DateListPlot?

Tags: plotting, graphics

Is there a way to rotate TickMarks in DateListPlot to avoid overlap, eg:

[image]

Part of the code used to generate this is:

```
TimelineGr[file_] := 
 DateListPlot[{{First[#], 1}, {Last[#], Length@#}} &@
   Sort@Flatten[ Last /@ I2B2[file, dateIntervals], 1], 
  Epilog -> ({Text[First@#, {First@Last@#, First@#2}, {1, 0}], Blue, 
       Rectangle[{First@Last@#, First@#2}, {Last@Last@#, 
         First@#2 + 0.1}]} &~MapIndexed ~ I2B2[file, dateIntervals]),
  PlotRange -> All, AspectRatio -> 1/4, ImageSize -> 800, 
  DateTicksFormat -> {"Year", "/", "Month", "/", "Day"}, 
  FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, { 
     First[Last[#]] & /@ I2B2[file, dateIntervals], Automatic}}, 
  PlotLabel -> file <> ".xml"
  ]
```

(Note, this includes custom functions)

If not, this is just another example of why it's almost always better to write visualization from the bottom-up

Comment: See my somewhat relevant question also: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2652/labeling-a-bar-chart-changing-how-rotated-labels-are-centered

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Perhaps something like this?

```
data = {{{2006, 10, 1}, 10}, {{2006, 10, 15}, 12},
        {{2006, 10, 30}, 15}, {{2006, 11, 20}, 20}};

p = DateListPlot[data];

Show[p,
  Options[p, FrameTicks] /. s_String :> Rotate[s, 90 Degree]
]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If one prefers not to use `Show` then:

```
p /. x : (FrameTicks -> _) :> (x /. s_String :> Rotate[s, 90 Degree])
```

Comment: Outstanding. Is there a way to inline it or is the call to Show necessary?

Comment: @alancalvitti when you say "inline" do you mean do this entirely from within `DateListPlot` with options?  If so, not that I know of.  Otherwise I'm not sure what you mean.  You could do it with only `/.` and not `Show` but I think it will be less clean; nevertheless if you want that I'll post it.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard, This is not working in the current MMA version. V10.3

Answer (score 10):

Mr.Wizard has shown you how to rotate the labels. Sometimes, it might also be useful to simply offset alternate labels so that it doesn't clash and is more readable. For example:

```
Block[{i = 1},
    DateListPlot[data, DateTicksFormat -> {"Day", "/", "Month", "/", "Year"}] /. 
        s_String :> If[s =!= "" && OddQ[i], i += 1; s, i += 1; Column[{"", s}]]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. The next level is to spread out TickMarks when they are not regularly spaced and cluster in time. The graphic I included in my post shows a simple example but it gets a lot worse with TimeML data where some dates are days others months others years and all should be covered in a single timeline.

Answer (score 10):

Given that the original question already uses so many different options, I think the most obvious answer is the one that makes use of exactly these existing options. This requires no post-processing whatsoever. By post-processing, I mean the replacement rules `s_String :> ...`

```
data = {{{2006, 10, 1}, 10}, {{2006, 10, 25}, 12}, {{2006, 10, 30}, 
    15}, {{2006, 11, 20}, 20}};

DateListPlot[
 data,
 FrameTicks -> 
  {
   {Automatic, None},
   {
    Map[
     {#,
       Framed[
        Rotate[
         DateString[#, {"Year", "/", "Month", "/", "Day"}],
         90 Degree]
        , RoundingRadius -> 5,
        FrameStyle -> None,
        Background -> LightOrange
        ],
       {0, .01}
       } &,
     data[[All, 1]]
     ],
    None}
   }
 ]
```

[image: datelistRotated]

All the heavy lifting is done by the `FrameTicks` option. The list `data` contains all the information necessary to create the positions and text for the tick labels, more precisely we need only the first entries: `data[[All, 1]]`.

The `Map` command uses each date entry in `data[[All, 1]]` to create a list that identifies a tick mark with a position and label. The label part is rotated by `90` degrees - I also chose to add a rounded rectangle background using `Framed`, and make the tick mark extend outside the frame toward the label, by using a tuple `{0, .01}` for the tick length specification.

This approach has some potential advantages, other than making full use of the existing options: in particular, making pattern replacements in a post-processing step may require more carefully crafted conditions (instead of `s_String`) if  some of the labels on the *vertical* axis happen to be customized with strings too (e.g., instead of purely numbers from `0` to `20`, you could have one special tick labeled by a word like `"special value"` - then that word would unintentionally get rotated along with the date labels).

See also [this answer to a closely related question, "Centering date labels over the year in a DateListPlot"](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/827/245)

Comment: To be fair, op didn't have code in the question until later well after both answers were given and one accepted... :)

Comment: @R.M Ah, I see - one of those telepathic answers where you had to divine the question first.

Comment: This isn't a contest. But I'm glad SE exists - it's the best thing since ice cubes. Particuarly since WRI charges $300/hr for professional services.

Comment: @alancalvitti It's not a contest, so I guess winning is even harder. That just adds to the challenge.

Answer (score 2):

An answer in the same vein as @Mr.Wizard's, but that works in more recent versions of Mathematica:

```
data = {{{2006, 10, 1}, 10}, {{2006, 10, 15}, 12}, {{2006, 10, 30}, 15}, {{2006, 11, 20}, 20}};

dlp = DateListPlot[data];

(*get x plotrange*)
xpr = First[PlotRange /. Options[dlp, PlotRange]];

(*get the frameticks that DateListPlot uses by default from the internal function*)
ticks = (Charting`DateTicksFunction[Automatic, DateTicksFormat -> {Automatic}] @@ xpr);

(* manually adjust styling (adding rotation) for ticks gathered above *)
rotatedTicks = Replace[
     ticks, 
     {x_, Style[y_String, specs__], z_List, d_Directive} :> {x, Style[Rotate[y, 80 Degree], specs], z, d}, 
     {1}
];

(*add our "custom" ticks back into the plot*)
Show[
     dlp, 
     FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {rotatedTicks, Automatic}}
]
```

[image: rotated ticks pic]

This gets the ticks manually from the internal `` Charting`DateTicksFunction `` function, and then post-processes them and plugs them back into the graphics object.

YMMV, and this uses internal functionality that may change in a future release.

Comment: `Rotate` rotates the text around its center. If you add `GridLines -> Automatic` and change the rotation angle to 45 the tick labels look offset from the grid. Is there a way to rotate so that the end of the label lines up with the grid? I tried setting the third argument to `Rotate` to `{Right, Center}` but that seemed to have no effect.