# Make Plot look like Bloomberg terminal

Tags: plotting, graphics, options

I've always wanted to make my financial `Plot`s look like a Bloomberg terminal. How would I go about making my chart look like one?

I am talking specifically about the chart gradient background, the gradient plot fill, the dashed horizontal and vertical markers, and the markers on the right y axis.

Here is the image I am using as a template:

[image: Bloomberg terminal]

Any pointers would be appreciated!

Comment: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/2988/can-i-make-a-plot-with-gradient-filling covers the gradients

Comment: I think you need to motivate this question a lot better to be in with a chance of receiving a serious answer. You could think of it this way: maybe I've always wanted to visit Australia, but if my only effort towards that is to post on the Internet asking for someone to buy me tickets, is it going to happen?

Comment: Also relevant: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/825/8

Comment: Would something like [that](http://i.stack.imgur.com/nniBf.png) be good enough?

Comment: @Öskå that's pretty damn close. Did you make that yourself?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks to [this](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/16137/1356) answer for the gradient filling you can do the following:

```
sign[text_, xc_, size_] := 
  Graphics[{FaceForm[White], EdgeForm[Thin], 
    Polygon[{{0, 0}, {.25, -.40}, {2.5, -.40}, {2.5, .40}, {.25, .40}}], 
    Style[Text[Round[text, .01], {1.25, 0}], size, Black]}, ImageSize -> Scaled[xc]]
gradientBackground = 
  With[{bottomColor = Black, topColor = Hue@.6}, 
    Inset[Show[Rasterize[Graphics[Polygon[{{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
      VertexColors -> {bottomColor, bottomColor, topColor, topColor}],
      PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> 0], "Image"], 
      AspectRatio -> Full], {Left, Bottom}, {0, 0}, 
      ImageScaled[{1, 1}]]];

SeedRandom@0;
bankerData = Transpose[{Range[100], Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 100]] + 10}];
last = Last@bankerData;
ypoints = Last /@ bankerData;

grid = Grid[{{"Day session:", SpanFromLeft}, {"Last Price", Last@last}, 
  {"Highest", Max@(Last /@ bankerData)}, {"Average", Mean@(Last /@ bankerData)}, 
  {"Lowest", Min@(Last /@ bankerData)}}];

lp = ListLinePlot[bankerData, Prolog -> gradientBackground, 
  PlotRangePadding -> None, Frame -> True, Axes -> False, 
  FrameTicks -> {
    {All, Thread[{Range[Round[Min@ypoints], Round[Max@ypoints]], 
        Grid[{{"", #}}, Spacings -> .80] & /@ (# <> ".00" & /@ 
           ToString /@ Range[Round[Min@ypoints], Round[Max@ypoints]])}]~
      Join~{{Last@last, sign[Last@last, 45, 11]}}},{All, All}},
  FrameTicksStyle -> {{Opacity@0, White}, {White, Opacity@0}},      
  GridLines -> Automatic, GridLinesStyle -> Dashed, 
  PlotStyle -> White, Method -> {"GridLinesInFront" -> True}, 
  Background -> Black, PlotRegion -> {{.04, .96}, {.04, .96}}, 
  Filling -> Top, FillingStyle -> Directive@{Opacity@.8, GrayLevel@.1}, 
  BaseStyle -> {White, FontFamily -> "Arial"}, PlotRange -> All, 
  Epilog -> Inset[Framed[grid, Background -> Directive[{Black, Opacity@.5}]], 
    Scaled[{.5, .2}]], ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Fantastic. I didn't expect such level of detail when I asked the question. Thank you!

Comment: @Aron My pleasure :) I guess the little spiky ticks can be done as well, I will spend some time on them later on :)

Comment: @Aron I guess I will stick to that, I can't make the spikes look correct, they don't stick to the _y-axis_.. :)